# What is the lambda function to compute mean of each column/row in a dataframe (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

What is the lambda function to compute the mean of each column/row in a data frame (pandas)?

I am trying to get the mean of each column of my data frame by lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lambda function to compute the mean of each column (if you want to compute the mean of each row just put `axis=1`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 15, 'b': 15, 'c': 5},
                   {'a': 20, 'b': 10, 'c': 7},
                   {'a': 25, 'b': 30, 'c': 9}])

df.apply(lambda col: sum(col) / len(col), axis=0)
```

This is the result:

```
a    20.000000
b    18.333333
c     7.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a lot of methods like, for a single column:

```
df['column'].mean() # enter column name in string format
```

Or you can use df.descibe() to get all information per column like mean,standard deviation e.t.c...

```
df.describe()
```

Comment: Your df.described() gave me an interesting idea:

df.append(df.describe().loc['mean'])

Comment: I know about it already. thanks tho.

Answer (score -1):

taking mean of each row using lambda:

`DataFrame.apply(lambda row: sum(row)/len(row), axis=1)`

for each column:

`DataFrame.apply(lambda cl: sum(cl)/len(cl), axis=0)`